# How to create a Endless game like grim jogger or zombie tsunami Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to make a game like grim jogger or zombie tsunami as I did not know where to start
I do not know how to create a bunch of people and the press jumped on every one of them will jump up and fall down
anyone have any idea or could help me with demos
sorry for my english

Comment: Go and research prefabs, instantiating from the resource folder, OO Scrpting, think of some math to generate the endless terrain patterns and then come back to us :)

Comment: Start with basics: Try official unity tutorials. Try to code at least some basics. We cannot write game for you, but we will help you solve your coding problems later

Comment: I do not know how to create a group of people to follow the leader . The head moving or jumping onto the rear respectively users follow

Answer (score 0):

I think you have never used unity before. If yes then follow these tutorials first.

http://www.unity3dstudent.com/

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a lot of problems to solve on a game like Zombie Tsunami. But write your problems step-by-step before start coding is a great start.

1) Level Parallax (easy to achieve)

2) Plataforms and Obstacles (you need to calculate minimum and maximum gaps to avoid level issues)

3) Level Animation (will keep platforms, obstacles, explosions, etc.. sync)

4) Player could be a vector of your particulary structure (Sprites, GameObject, etc..) and you need to iterate on it to achieve jump for all children

5) Collisions
...

Hope it helps. Good Luck